# simple if statement translated from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

I currently program in Python and am learning javascript with Nicolas C. Zakas [Professional Javascript for Web Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026691). So I came across this example:

```
if (test){
test = false;
alert(test);
}
```

So I tried to compare it to what it'd be like to write the same concept in Python

```
if test == False:
   print (test)
```

Is my comparison right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my comparison right?

Not exactly.

- The Javascript example is testing if `test` is true in a boolean
  context. You can do the exact same thing in Python.
- The Javascript example also sets `test` to false, which you don't do

With the above changes your code becomes:

```
if test:
    test = False
    print (test)
```

Simple, actually. One big point to note however is that Python and Javascript have very different ideas of what objects are consider "truthy" and "falsy". If unsure, best to check the docs for each language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book, but if `test` is just a boolean, then you have it just slightly backwards: the JavaScript version checks if `test` is true, so in Python, you would want `if test == True` or more simply, `if test`.

However, if `test` is anything else, it gets more complex, because if "truthy" values in both [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html), which means the behaviour is not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
if test:
    test = False
    print(test)
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation. Posting just code is not instructing

Comment: Many people visit these pages to learn, so anything you can add to an explanation will help.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)